# Converting Ipyparallel to Dask - Where is the Web UI

Tags: python, ipython, dask, ipython-parallel

I have set up a cluster with ipyparallel on my local machine and wish to convert it to a dask cluster. My primary motivation for this is to be able to use the web ui with dask (via bokeh) to monitor the performance.

When I convert the ipyparallel cluster to a dask cluster, it does not start the bokeh web ui. Does anyone know how to launch the web UI either in the become_dask() function or after I have started dask

```
client_ipp = ipp.Client(profile='ipp_1')
dview  = client_ipp[:]
bview = client_ipp.load_balanced_view()

e = client_ipp.become_dask()
e
```

> Client
>
> ```
> Scheduler: tcp://XX.XXX.X.XX:XXXXX
> ```
>
> Cluster
>
> ```
> Workers: 8
> Cores: 8
> Memory: 33.60 GB
> ```

If I start a cluster directly with Dask I get:

```
from distributed import client
c3 = Client()
c3
```

> Client
>
> ```
> Scheduler: tcp://XXX.X.X.X:XXXXX
> Dashboard: http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXXX
> ```
>
> Cluster
>
> ```
> Workers: 8
> Cores: 8
> Memory: 33.60 GB
> ```

Comment: This is discussed here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1268 .  If you feel like fixing this that would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the info MRocklin. I will take a look...